# Weird output of 12.04 server on terminal from the start

Tags: 12.04, server, console, xbmc

I'm trying to install XBMC on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. After installing `nvidia-current` and `xinit`, the machine boots up in text mode, no surprise there, but just prints bogus letters like shown in the picture.

[image]

I've no idea what went wrong. I'd apreciate your help.

My graphics card according to `lspci` is a gforce 8200:

```
% lspci
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller (rev a2)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus (rev a1)
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:01.3 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor (rev a2)
00:01.4 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a1)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev a1)
00:04.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a1)
00:04.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller (rev a1)
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE (rev a1)
00:07.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio (rev a1)
00:08.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge (rev a1)
00:09.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode) (rev a2)
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP77 Ethernet (rev a2)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:12.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge (rev a1)
00:14.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge (rev a1)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV44 [GeForce 7100 GS] (rev a1)
```

The TV is hooked up via a DVI-HDMI cable, which I checked. So this is not the problem.
I'm using `zsh` but `bash` behaves the same way.

```
% reset
```

did not work either.

Login works normally, so typing in a user name and password is working. Just the output is weird.

The boot prompt with all status information is scrambled like this as well.

thanks for any tips.
flowolf

Comment: Are you gonna need performance using your graphic card? If not, try using nouveau driver.

Comment: thanks. uninstalling the nvidia drivers worked. i'll try nouveau.

Comment: what i did to resolve the issue was uninstalling nvidia-common -current ... etc.:
    
    # aptitude remove nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings xserver-xorg  xinit

i then installed nouveau-firmware
  
    # aptitude install nouveau-firmware xorg
    # reboot

the first part of the booting process still prints bogus but that get's better when the correct drivers are loaded.

i'll repost this after the 8 hours have past, in which i'm not allowed to answer my own question (new user)

Answer (score 0):

*The OP answered the question [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228295/weird-output-of-12-04-server-on-terminal-from-the-start#comment281767_228295). Here's the relevant part, with a few modifications for clarity.*

What I did to resolve the issue was uninstalling `nvidia-common`, `-current`, etc. As root:

```
aptitude remove nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings xserver-xorg xinit i then installed nouveau-firmware
aptitude install nouveau-firmware xorg
```

Reboot.

The first part of the booting process still prints bogus messages. But that gets better when the correct drivers are loaded.